# Excel font data

Tags: microsoft-excel, fonts

I have a Excel Spreadsheet that uses a specific font, but I cannot find the font data anywhere on my PC. I pasted a bunch of Unicode characters into it and applied the suggested Excel import assist to use the already-in-use-formatting of the spreadsheet and the ones I expected the font to have, where there in the right style (font).

Example of the above described process:

[image: Example of the above described process]

[image: Part 2]

Any ideas on how to 'extract' the font data?

I know that it is no built-in font and it is not in the Mac Font Book. If I copy the cell from Excel and paste it in e.g. Pages it then gets substituted. It also gets substituted when I change the font size in Excel.
It seems like Excel can use fonts normally that are disabled in the Font Book, and I can't find a copy or something of the original font data for Excel to use.

I use Excel from the App Store running the latest version on MacOS Big Sur.

I already looked into the Excel package and the resource folders therein.

Comment: The Mac has some pretty  seamless font substitution routines [though tbh, I'm less certain as to how MS apps respond to those]. It's more than likely one of the built-in fonts. You could try pasting the same unicode into Font Book & see if you can find them. [or you could paste the unicode into your question & see if the same appears here]

Comment: I know that it is no built in font. If I copy the cell from Excel and paste it in e.g Pages it then gets substituted.

Comment: Well, without any further information, I've nothing left to offer - we don't have pictures or data; we only have a vague claim.

Comment: I hope my edit made the question a bit clearer

Comment: Not really. Excel can't embed fonts at all, so we really have nothing to go on. Pictures, examples of the specific unicode, even the name of the "specific font"… they would help.

Comment: The unicodes are of no importance besides showing that excel has some font data saved somewhere. Otherwise it couldn't display those -never before typed- symbols correctly. The name wouldn't help for it is a self-made font.

Comment: Excel cannot embed fonts, so that cannot be the case. Those particular unicodes are pretty basic - all accessible directly from any Mac keyboard, so they should be supported by any font. Your issue is merely… which font. The existing answer claiming Calibri must be a Windows-based answer. Mac doesn't have Calibri by default [not even on a machine with Office installed]. The images you added are far too small for any font recognition software to guess at.

Comment: You seem to not have understood my question. I know exactly which font is used. And I reckon that there must be some font data saved somewhere because these unicodes look exactly as they should, and Excel cannot have taken the information from already typed characters for those weren’t in the spreadsheet before.

Comment: If you know exactly which font is used, why did you not put that information in the question? Your spreadsheet picture says Ariel, but the lower image with the unicode is most definitely not Ariel. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCmll.png

Comment: Because it is a personal self-made font. And I hope I could made clear that I am not interested in the name but the actual .ttf data.

Comment: Sorry, you've completely lost me now. I have absolutely no idea what you want. Each 'clarification' just seems more guarded & opaque than the last.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Excel for Mac uses Body Font in font size 12, which is displayed as Calibri font in font size 12 when you type data in a worksheet, header or footer, or text box. However, you can change the default font and font size for all new workbooks that you create.

https://mk0spreadsheetp99p4q.kinstacdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Excel-options-to-change-default-font.jpg

To do this, you'll need to use VBA to identify/interact with the font data within Excel. This page covers quite a bit about how to do things like setting the font type, style, point size, etc. for worksheet ranges or individual cells.

https://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-font/

Comment: The font used in this spreadsheet does not appear in the list of fonts (your first link). I can only use it in other spreadsheet if they are a duplicate of the original. I would like to get the .ttf data of the font used by excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can Insert an object using the `Create from File` tab of the dialogue box which can then be accessed by VBA. That file can be a font file.

So one approach would be to examine the spreadsheet for objects and delve into any found. If one is a font file, steal it. (I mean `extract it`. Sure I do.)

An Excel file can be embedded within a Word file and the Word file itself can have fonts embedded which the embedded Excel file can then access. Directly since it is a part of the Word file and with VBA.

See if there is a Word file, or some similar wrapper for the Excel file, and examine it for embedded fonts. If there is one, steal it. (I mean `extract it`. Sure I do.)

As to embedding in other files, an Excel file, of the `.xlsx` variety, can be embedded in another Excel file, this one of the macro-enabled variety. That one can do all the following work (in a flash) ending with opening the one you are working in so you never really notice a macro-enabled file existed as many people do put things in `Trusted` directories so such piddling annoyances don't happen. (And who needs to display all those nasty file extensions? Turn that off too.)

In any case, the macro-enabled file can have a Word file embedded in it and that file can have the font embedded. So it's the source of the font information for the `.xlsm` file and its code loads the font name into the `system font table` so it is accessible to the working file.

Or one can do that pretty cleverly in the file itself so long as hiding the font isn't one's goal.

So look for macros and examine them for hints to the technique used and source of the font information. Note that the insertion into the system font table is NOT an installation of the font so does NOT trigger installation defenses in Windows (and, I assume a Mac as something gives me the impression you have one of them). It's just "there" until a macro pulls it or you restart.

You can use that trick if you have a font you need now and then, but don't want cluttering your font list.

If you find it, steal it. (I mean `extract it`. Sure I do.)

So, obviously I have an overarching concern here:  **SOMEONE went to a LOT of trouble to hide this font away from you, the user, presumably trying to keep you from taking it.** No offer is made to sell it to you. Could even be someone who has some messed up idea it was OK for HIM to steal it so long as he didn't compound that by distributing it. Whatever:  Someone went to a lot of trouble to keep it from you.

So it clearly `ain't right` for you to go after it.

That said, your morality (and you have demonstrated a singular singlemindedness in question and comments here so... momma said don't say nothin' if you can't say nothin' nice) is your own, I guess.

Personally, I think the Word-embedment would be obvious to you and the macro approaches too much work (unless the writer is the creator and owner of the font (yes, that doesn't bother you at all either, does it?) and is proud and possessive of it) so I'd concentrate on examining objects in the file. And any macros, but mainly objects.

I apologize ***to all others*** for sounding "preachy" here. But you have demonstrated a clear "I WANT THIS FONT" motive here and let it sound like you are actually annoyed people aren't in tune with that. It flat out doesn't give a good vibe at all. I've answered, not for you, but for others who might find ways to use the ideas in a positive manner.